# Google Play Developer AP Iconnection issues

Tags: android, authorization, google-play-developer-api

Hi we are trying to get Google Play subscriptions information connected to one of our Android apps. The first step is authorize and get subscriptions json

Has anyone succeed to work with Google Play Developer API? Authorization? Subscriptions list?

## Below is our experience

When I use authScope =  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher";
 (took it from Google Example)

```
    private static final String authScope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher";

am.getAuthToken(
    myAccount,                      // Account retrieved using    getAccountsByType()
    authScope,                      // Auth scope
    options,                        // Authenticator-specific options
    this,                           // Your activity
    new OnTokenAcquired(),          // Callback called when a token is successfully acquired
    new Handler(new OnError()));    // Callback called if an error occurs

private class OnTokenAcquired implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> {
@Override
public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> accountManagerFuture) {
    addProcessMessage("OnTokenAcquired");

    // Get the result of the operation from the AccountManagerFuture.
    try {
        Bundle bundle = accountManagerFuture.getResult();
        // The token is a named value in the bundle. The name of the value
        // is stored in the constant AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN.
        String token = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
        addProcessMessage("OnTokenAcquired token=" + token);
        processAcessSubscriptions(token);

    } catch ( Exception ae ) {
        Log.e(TAG, "OnTokenAcquired Exception=" + ae.getMessage(), ae);
        setProcessFailed(ae.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

I can’t get token, because I get exception below

```
OnTokenAcquired Exception=Unknown
                                                                    android.accounts.AuthenticatorException: Unknown
                                                                        at android.accounts.AccountManager.convertErrorToException(AccountManager.java:2213)
                                                                        at android.accounts.AccountManager.-wrap0(AccountManager.java)
                                                                        at android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask$Response.onError(AccountManager.java:2056)
                                                                        at android.accounts.IAccountManagerResponse$Stub.onTransact(IAccountManagerResponse.java:69)
                                                                        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)
```

When I use authScope = "Manage your tasks";
 (took it from another Google Example)

```
private static final String authScope = "Manage your tasks";
```

I'm receiving token, but on ProductPurchase product = purchases.products().get(PACKAGE_NAME, TEST_SKU, token).execute();

I am getting getProducts Exception=400 Bad Request
See below

```
        HttpTransport httpTransport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
 JacksonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
 AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
 InputStream is = assetManager.open(CLIENT_SECRET_JSON);
 GoogleCredential credential =       GoogleCredential.fromStream(is).createScoped(Collections.singleton(AndroidPublisherScopes.ANDROIDPUBLISHER));
 AndroidPublisher publisher = new AndroidPublisher.Builder(httpTransport,  jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName(APP_NAME).build();
 AndroidPublisher.Purchases purchases = publisher.purchases();
 ProductPurchase product = purchases.products().get(PACKAGE_NAME, TEST_SKU, token).execute();

 getProducts Exception=400 Bad Request
                                                                  {
                                                                    "code" : 400,
                                                                    "errors" : [ {
                                                                      "domain" : "global",
                                                                      "message" : "Invalid Value",
                                                                      "reason" : "invalid"
                                                                    } ],
                                                                    "message" : "Invalid Value"
                                                                  }
                                                                      com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
                                                                  {
                                                                    "code" : 400,
                                                                    "errors" : [ {
                                                                      "domain" : "global",
                                                                      "message" : "Invalid Value",
                                                                      "reason" : "invalid"
                                                                    } ],
                                                                    "message" : "Invalid Value"
                                                                  }
                                                                      at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
                                                                      at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
                                                                      at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
                                                                      at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
                                                                      at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
                                                                      at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
                                                                      at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)


 Main Activity
package com.lemi.affilatemanager;

import android.Manifest;
import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback;
import android.accounts.AccountManagerFuture;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
 import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
 import com.google.api.services.androidpublisher.AndroidPublisher;
 import com.google.api.services.androidpublisher.AndroidPublisherScopes;
import com.google.api.services.androidpublisher.model.ProductPurchase;

 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.util.Collections;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
private static final int DIALOG_ACCOUNTS = 11;
public static final String CLIENT_SECRET_JSON = "service_account.json";//"client_secret.json";
public static final String APP_NAME = "AffilateManager";
public static final String PACKAGE_NAME = "com.lemi.keywordmarketingautoresponder";
private AccountManager accountManager;
private Account myAccount;

protected static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST = 10;

private TextView resultText;
private StringBuilder testMessage = new StringBuilder();
private ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    resultText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test_result);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    Button startProcessButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_process_btn);
    startProcessButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            test();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_ACCOUNTS:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Select a Google account");
            final Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
            final int size = accounts.length;
            String[] names = new String[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                names[i] = accounts[i].name;
            }
            builder.setItems(names, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Stuff to do when the account is selected by the user
                    myAccount = accounts[which];
                    processGetAuthToken();
                }
            });
            return builder.create();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult requestCode=" + requestCode);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST:
            test();
            break;

        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}

private void test () {

    boolean canReadContacts = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    Log.i(TAG, "test canReadContacts=" + canReadContacts);
    if ( !canReadContacts ) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS}, PERMISSION_REQUEST);
        return;
    }

    startProcess();

    if ( getAccount() ) {
        processGetAuthToken();
    }
}

private void startProcess () {

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    testMessage.delete(0, testMessage.length());
    resultText.setText(testMessage);
}

private void setProcessFailed ( final String message ) {

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            addProcessMessage(message);
        }});
}

private void addProcessMessage ( String message ) {

    Log.i(TAG, message);
    testMessage.append("\n").append(message);
    resultText.setText(testMessage);
}

private boolean getAccount () {

    Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");

    if ( accounts == null || accounts.length < 1 || accounts.length > 1) {
        showDialog(DIALOG_ACCOUNTS);
        return false;
    }

    myAccount = accounts[0];
    return true;
}

private static final String authScope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher";
//private static final String authScope = "Manage your tasks";//https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher";
//private static final String authScope = "Financial Access Enabled Account";

private void processGetAuthToken() {

    addProcessMessage("Start processGetAuthToken process...");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
    Bundle options = new Bundle();

    //am.invalidateAuthToken(accountType, authTocken);

    am.getAuthToken(
            myAccount,                      // Account retrieved using getAccountsByType()
            authScope,                      // Auth scope
            options,                        // Authenticator-specific options
            this,                           // Your activity
            new OnTokenAcquired(),          // Callback called when a token is successfully acquired
            new Handler(new OnError()));    // Callback called if an error occurs

}

private static final String TEST_SKU = "subs:com.lemi.keywordmarketingautoresponder:keywordmarketingautoresponder.1month.1keyword";

private void processAcessSubscriptions( String token ) {

    addProcessMessage("processAcessSubscriptions token=" + token);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //AndroidPublisher.Purchases ap = null;
    try {
        //NetHttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        HttpTransport httpTransport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
        JacksonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream is = assetManager.open(CLIENT_SECRET_JSON);
        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(is).createScoped(Collections.singleton(AndroidPublisherScopes.ANDROIDPUBLISHER));
        AndroidPublisher publisher = new AndroidPublisher.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName(APP_NAME).build();
        addProcessMessage("processAcessSubscriptions publisher=" + publisher);

        getProducts(token, publisher);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "processAcessSubscriptions Exception:" + e.getMessage(), e);
        setProcessFailed(e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void getProducts(final String token, final AndroidPublisher publisher) {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            try {
                AndroidPublisher.Purchases purchases = publisher.purchases();
                addProcessMessage("getProducts purchases=" + purchases);
                ProductPurchase product = purchases.products().get(PACKAGE_NAME, TEST_SKU, token).execute();
                Integer purchaseState = product.getPurchaseState();
                addProcessMessage("getProducts purchaseState=" + purchaseState);
                long time = product.getPurchaseTimeMillis();
                int consuptionState = product.getConsumptionState();
                String developerPayload = product.getDeveloperPayload();
                addProcessMessage("getProducts time=" + time + " consuptionState=" + consuptionState + " developerPayload=" + developerPayload);
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                Log.e(TAG, "getProducts Exception=" + e.getMessage(), e);
                setProcessFailed(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

        private class OnTokenAcquired implements AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> {
            @Override
            public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> accountManagerFuture) {
                addProcessMessage("OnTokenAcquired");
                // Get the result of the operation from the AccountManagerFuture.
                try {
                    Bundle bundle = accountManagerFuture.getResult();

                    // The token is a named value in the bundle. The name of the value
                    // is stored in the constant AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN.
                    String token = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                    addProcessMessage("OnTokenAcquired token=" + token);
                    processAcessSubscriptions(token);

                } catch ( Exception ae ) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "OnTokenAcquired Exception=" + ae.getMessage(), ae);
                    setProcessFailed(ae.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }

        private class OnError implements Handler.Callback {
            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
                Log.i(TAG, "OnError handleMessage=" + message);
                setProcessFailed(message.toString());
                return false;
            }
        }

}
```